# How to ORDER MYSQL query by nearest distance first in a LIKE %% query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code that searches MYSQL using LIKE %% and it works fine.

Now i need to add one more thing to this query so it searches the MYQL database using the *LIKE %% AND ORDER BY nearest lat/long*.

This is my code:

```
$term = $_GET['term']; 


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM YO_businesses WHERE category LIKE '%$term%'";
   $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
   $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);



    $records = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     $records[] = $row;


      }


echo '' . json_encode($records, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . '';
```

I need to add something like this to the above query but not sure how to:

```
$lon = //your longitude
$lat = //your latitude
$miles = //your search radius

$query = "SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$lon') ) + 
sin( radians('$lat') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM yourtable HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5"
```

Could someone please advice on this?

Comment: What's the problem with what you have except that you should use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` as you're not aggregating and parameterize your queries?

Comment: @stickybit the problem is don't know how to combine the codes above.

Comment: Add combine the expressions after `SELECT` with a comma and the predicates in the `WHERE` clause with an `AND` and append your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause. Unless `YO_businesses` and `yourtable` are indeed different tables that is. In that case you need to describe how the tables are related. Best is you also add the `CREATE` statements of the tables to the question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any potentially unsafe values incorporated into SQL text must be properly escaped to mitigate SQL injection vulnerabilities. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

(better pattern is prepared statements with bind placeholders, but if we can't do that, at a minimum, we can make "sql safe" copies of the values, and include those in the SQL text

```
$ss_term = $db_conx->real_escape_string($db_conx,$term);
$ss_lat  = $db_conx->real_escape_string($db_conx,$lat);
$ss_lon  = $db_conx->real_escape_string($db_conx,$lon);
```

To return all the rows in ascending distance from $lat,$lon, we can include the GCD calculation in the `ORDER BY` clause, something like this:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT b.*
   FROM YO_businesses b 
  WHERE b.category LIKE CONCAT('%" . $ss_term ."%')
  ORDER
     BY -- great circle distance calculation
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('" . $ss_lat . "') )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.latitude ) )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.longitude ) 
                            - RADIANS('" . $ss_lon . "') 
                          )
                     + SIN( RADIANS('" . $ss_lat . "') )
                     * SIN( RADIANS( b.latitude ) ) 
                 ) 
        ) ASC" ;
```

---

If we also want to return the calculated distance as part of the resultset, we can relocate the calculation into the `SELECT` list of the query.

```
$sql =
"SELECT b.*
      , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('" . $ss_lat . "') )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.latitude ) )
                     * COS( RADIANS( b.longitude ) 
                            - RADIANS('" . $ss_lon . "') 
                          )
                     + SIN( RADIANS('" . $ss_lat . "') )
                     * SIN( RADIANS( b.latitude ) ) 
                 ) 
        ) AS gc_distance
   FROM YO_businesses b 
  WHERE b.category LIKE CONCAT('%" . $ss_term ."%')";
```

And with that in the `SELECT` list, we can reference that calculated value by the correlation name (assigned alias `gc_distance` in an `ORDER BY` clause

We can add a LIMIT clause to limit the number of rows returned, or if we want to not return rows that have a gc_distance greater than some value, before the `ORDER BY` clause we can include a condition in a `HAVING` clause

```
$sql .= "
 HAVING gc_distance < 100
  ORDER
     BY gc_distance ASC";
```

---

Note:

Some comments in the question are pointing out the usage of the `HAVING` clause. In the SQL shown in the question, the usage of `HAVING` is valid.

The comments are correct in as far as conditions to be evaluated when rows are accessed must appear in the `WHERE` clause or in the `ON` clause.

Conditions in the `HAVING` clause are evaluated later in statement processing, after the rows are accessed. Because the results of aggregate functions (e.g. SUM(), COUNT(), AVG() are not available when rows are being accessed, conditions on these results cannot be included in the `WHERE` clause, which I think leads to this misinformed notion that we can't use `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY` or without aggregate functions.

Comment: I made a mistake and chose the othe answer as the correct answer but this answer should've been chosen. I do apologies and now i corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ST_Distance_Sphere`-function to calculate distance between lat/lng pairs:

```
select ST_Distance_Sphere( point(longitude1 , latitude1), point(longitude2, latitude2))
```

This will give you distance in meters.

To use it both in `select` and in `where` you can use same expression in both parts:

```
$query = "
select *, 
  ST_Distance_Sphere( 
    point(longitude1 , latitude1), 
    point($lon, $lat)
  ) as 'distance'
from YO_businesses
where ST_Distance_Sphere( 
    point(longitude1 , latitude1), 
    point($lon, $lat)
  ) < miles/1609.344
order by distance ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5";
```

Comment: that wasn't the question really! the question was how to combine my own code that's currently working with the second code that I provided in my question.

Comment: So what is the relation between the `YO_businesses`-table and the `yourtable`-table?

Comment: YO_businesses tabel is my table and the youttable is just a random name I suppose.

Comment: In which table do you have the `latitude` and `longitude`-columns?

Comment: in the YO_businesses table.

Comment: See the answer. A `HAVING`-clause is used only with `GROUP BY`-clause which you do not have as you do not have any aggregate functions. So, use `WHERE`-clause and put the condition there.

Comment: @slaakso: that's not true. A HAVING clause is valid without a GROUP BY, usage of HAVING clause as shown in the question is entirely valid.

Comment: The purpose of a HAVING-clause is to filter groups / aggregate functions in SELECT whereas WHERE-filters the rows. While current version of MySQL does allow use of  HAVING without GROUP BY / aggregate function (similarily it allowed more liberal use of GROUP BY-colums in pre 5.7), the purpose of the query is to limit the rows not groups, so a better and more standard way is to use WHERE to limit the rows.